# How can I fix my git history after accidentally deleting a file and adding it back in a different location?

Tags: git

Here's my situation: I moved a file to a new location, but accidentally only committed the deletion. Then in a subsequent commit, I committed the new file in the new location. `git log --follow` seems to not detect that the file was moved, and so doesn't show me the full history for that file now.

I then tried to fix this by moving the file back to its original location, but it still has its truncated history now lol, repair fail.

How can I now fix this file to make git detect the history chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to merge the two commits together:

```
git reset --soft "HEAD^"
git commit --amend
```

Or you can go back to the previous commit completely, redo the stuff and amend the commit:

```
git reset --hard "HEAD^"
# create the file, or move, ...
git commit --amend
```

At the end, if you already pushed to remote, you need to use `-f` to overwrite the remote history:

```
git push origin -f
```

Comment: Is `git push origin -f` needed for both options?

Comment: @BT : yes, whenever the history is modified

Comment: Got it, I did something very similar using rebase (git rebase -i HEAD~5) and then squashed all but 1 of the commits and pushed without the -f argument (forgot about it). The history works fine now, tho I do still have the original commits in the history. Possibly not as clean as your method, but it got me what I wanted. I followed this guide for merging commits: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html . Thanks!